# Setting margin for \thanks footnote

Tags: footnotes

I can use

```
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}
```

to indent a footnote.

How do I indent `\thanks` the same way?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{setspace} % Allows linespacing changes (see \onehalfspace)
    \usepackage{xltxtra} % For OpenType fonts
    \usepackage{titlesec} % For setting Section heading font
    \usepackage{titling} % For setting Title font
    \usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinking the Table of Contents
    \usepackage{adforn} % For ornaments
    \usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc} % For removing the stupid footnote indents
    \usepackage{easylist} % For better list environments
    \usepackage{enumitem} % An alternative list environment

    \begin{document}
    \title{Hello World}
    \author{Author Name\thanks{Thanks to the dog!}}
    \date{10 September 2013}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}
    \maketitle
    \onehalfspace
    \input{Text.tex}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What about using `\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}` before your `\thanks` command and `\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}` after to reset everything nicely?

Comment: This had no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide us more information about your document (class, packages, etc.)? It wouldbe nice to have a MWE with what you already tried.

Comment: MWE added, @LudovicC.

Comment: There is no `\footenotemargin` length with standard LaTeX without any package (also `\onehalfspace` requires `setspace`, but it seems irrelevant for the example).

Comment: @egreg, I have added the packages. Is there a way to set the margin for the `\thanks` command?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\maketitle`, by default, redefines the commands for typesetting the footnote. Here's a way for avoiding this redefinition:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % For OpenType fonts
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % modify commands and many other things
\makeatletter
%%% We don't want to redefine \@makefntext
\patchcmd\maketitle{\@makefntext}{\@@@ddt}{}{}
%%% We don't want to have \rlap around the footnote mark
\patchcmd\maketitle{\rlap}{\mbox}{}{}
\makeatother

%%%% hyperref should be last
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinking the Table of Contents

%%%% lipsum just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello World}
\author{Author Name\thanks{Thanks to the dog!}}
\date{10 September 2013}

\maketitle

A\footnote{xyz}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I've removed the inessential packages. Notice that you should call `fontspec` rather than `xltxtra`. It used to be the other way around, but quite long ago and `fontspec` has been improved since.

[image]