# Flush \thanks to the left margin and turn of text justification

Tags: footnotes, titling

I use `footmisc` to modify the layout of my footnotes such that the footnote marker and the footnote text flush to the left margin, and I turn off the justification and hyphenation in the footnotes with `\raggedright`.

How can I do these things in the argument of the `\thanks` command? Since I tend to use the package `titling` for modifying `\maketitle`, I assume it's best to stick to that package for modifying `\thanks` as well. The problem is that I understand almost nothing of the documentation for that package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
    \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\raggedright}
\begin{document}
\title{My title\thanks{These are the people I wish to thank. I need to add more words to
 demonstrate that there is right-edge justification in this line.}}
\maketitle
A sentence.\footnote{A footnote which I intend to be long enough to demonstrate that
 there is no right-edge justification.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you see this one? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135911/setting-margin-for-thanks-footnote

Comment: @egreg: Will that not interfere with my usage of ``titling`` for modifying other parts of ``\maketitle`` (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136285/insert-text-between-title-and-author)?

Comment: Well, in your code you aren't mentioning `titling`. Please, make the question as selfcontained as possible.

Comment: @egreg There's a certain tension here between being minimal and being "self-contained". It's hard to know in advance if answers will be incompatible with other packages one normally uses (and to be fair, I highlighted ``titling`` in my question and tagged my question with ``titling``). That said, I've modified my question slightly to show that I'd prefer to use ``titling`` (under the assumption that that would be the best solution).

Comment: OK, I understand what you're saying, but I remain of the opinion that you should add `titling` also here. The solution I give below should be compatible with the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `titling` it is easier on one side and more difficult on the other. However it's possible to replicate the setup made by `footmisc` also for the `\thanks` footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the page frame

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em} % just to show clearly equal output

\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\raggedright}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\makethanksmark}{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
      \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\thanksfootmark\hss}%
    \else
      \thanksfootmark
    \fi
  }%
  \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
  \rightmargin\z@
  \linewidth \columnwidth
  \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
  \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
  \footnotesize
  \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
  \leavevmode\raggedright %%% <--- add \raggedright
  \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
  \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
  \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thanksfootmark}{%
 {\normalfont\thanksscript{\thanksfootpre\tamark\thanksfootpost}}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{My title\thanks{These are the people I wish to thank. I need to add more words to
 undoubtedly demonstrate that there is right-edge justification in this line.}}

\maketitle

A sentence.\footnote{A footnote which I intend to be long enough to demonstrate that
 there is no right-edge justification.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code between ``makeatletter`` and ``makeatother``, that is only to add ``\raggedright`` to the thanks footnote?

Comment: @Sverre No, it's needed for getting the same paragraph shape with `\thanks` as with `\footnote`. I adapted the entire code from `footmisc` when the `hang` option is issued and also added `\raggedright`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the ``titling`` option be, which you call "easier on one side and more difficult on the other"? I'm just not sure if I should end up with a document that uses ``titling`` to modify all the properties of ``\maketitle`` except the ``\thanks`` command, since ``titling`` is supposed to cover that too.

Comment: @Sverre With `titling` it's easier to modify the title block's appearance; but it makes a bit more difficult obtaining the alignment you want.

Comment: So I shouldn't even bother with it, in other words? I.e. it is more complicated than the code you're suggesting above?

Comment: @Sverre Sorry, but I can't understand. You *are* using `titling`, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ``titling``. I was under the impression that your code does _not_ use ``titling``. Am I wrong? Is your solution the ``titling`` solution?

Comment: @Sverre Yes, it's redefining `\makethanksmark` that's a `titling` command.